# How to str_replace Google News RSS for Facebook Share?

Tags: regex, rss, preg-match, simplexml, str-replace

Hi I'm using **simpleXML** to display a **news.google.com** feed.

The displayed entries link to the original article in this way:

http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNEcqhcp4AfUzgxc2l1gumydaxQ-KQ&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52778832126843&ei=keFLVfiHGvDVmQL5_4GgBg&url=http://WEBSITEWITHNEWS.COM/ARTICLEURLHERE

I need the entries to link to this instead:
http://WEBSITEWITHNEWS.COM/ARTICLEURLHERE

The reason is that **Facebook Sharer** cannot interpret the following link:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&ct2=us&usg=AFQjCNEcqhcp4AfUzgxc2l1gumydaxQ-KQ&clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&cid=52778832126843&ei=keFLVfiHGvDVmQL5_4GgBg&url=http://WEBSITEWITHNEWS.COM/ARTICLEURLHERE

**Facebook Sharer** needs it to look like this:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://WEBSITEWITHNEWS.COM/ARTICLEURLHERE

Is there a way that I can use **regex (str_replace or preg_match)** to remove the Google redirect URL so that social sharing sites can recognize the link?

The Google redirect URL is dynamic and so it will be slightly different each time and so I will need something that can replace each variant.

My working, **functional code:**

```
    $feed = file_get_contents("https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=KEYWORD&output=rss");
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $entry){
  $date = $entry->pubDate; 
  $date = strftime("%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S%P", strtotime($date));
  $desc = $entry->description;
  $desc = str_replace("and more&nbsp;&raquo;", "","$desc");
  $desc = str_replace("font-size:85%", "font-size:100%","$desc");
  ?>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <?php echo $desc; ?>
  <div class="date">
  <?php echo $date; ?></div>
  <?php } ?>
 $desc = $entry->description;
 $date = $entry->pubDate; 
 $date = strftime("%A, %m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S", strtotime($date));
 $desc = str_replace("and more »","x","and more »");
  echo $date; 
  echo $desc;
  }
```

I'm using $desc to display the link instead of $link, but URL to the article with the Google redirectURL is still in $link if you would like to str_replace or preg_match $link instead of $desc

Link to working Google News feed below:
https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=KEYWORD&output=rss

If you know how to fix this you're a hero. Thank you Overflowers

Comment: So in `$desc` if you had `href="http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&amp;fd=R&amp;ct2=us&amp;usg=AFQjCNHG6ECOl4eSYKUWwztaiXMvxZGi1A&amp;clid=c3a7d30bb8a4878e06b80cf16b898331&amp;cid=52778831966961&amp;ei=oRRMVfjOLNqs3AGijoDoCQ&amp;url=http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2015/05/06/adwords-shortcuts"` you'd want `href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.wordstream.com/blog/ws/2015/05/06/adwords-shortcuts"`?

Comment: Well yes, sort of. I want to be able to allow people to share the article. If you used $desc to write it the way you said that would be great. It would be even better if I could just remove the redirect url in $link however.

Comment: The redirect URL being the one preceding `&amp;url=`?

Comment: Yes just like you said. I want to remove the entire URL up to and including &url=. So all(.*) until the second http://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in PHP functions [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) (split URL into components) and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) (get parameter values from query string) for this:

```
$feed = file_get_contents(
    "https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=KEYWORD&output=rss"
);
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $entry){
    // Get query part of link
    $query = parse_url($entry->link, PHP_URL_QUERY);

    // Parse query parameters into $params array
    parse_str($query, $params);

    // Get URL from parameters
    $url = $params['url'];

    // Just output in this example
    echo "URL: $url", PHP_EOL;

    // ... Do some more stuff
}
```

Output:

```
URL: http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/JonathanRaveh/20150506/242840/Death_of_the_app_keyword__whats_next.php
URL: http://www.business2community.com/online-marketing/8-keyword-optimization-tips-perfect-ppc-campaigns-01222200
URL: http://searchengineland.com/marry-keywords-compelling-content-218174
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from my first comment is using this regex.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$feed = file_get_contents("https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=KEYWORD&output=rss");
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $entry) {
    $date = $entry->pubDate;
    $date = strftime("%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S%P", strtotime($date));
    $desc = $entry->description;
    $desc = str_replace("and more&nbsp;&raquo;", "","$desc");
    $desc = str_replace("font-size:85%", "font-size:100%","$desc"); /*
    ?>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <?php // echo $desc; ?>
    <div class="date"><?php echo $date; ?></div>
    <?php
    */
    $desc = $entry->description;
    $desc = preg_replace('~href=".*?&amp;url=(.*?)"~', 'href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=$1"', $desc);
    $date = $entry->pubDate; 
    $date = strftime("%A, %m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S", strtotime($date));
    //$desc = str_replace("and more »","x","and more »");
    echo $date . "\n" . $desc;
    die('1 pass');
}
?>
```

Output (format altered for displaying):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="7" style="vertical-align:top;">
    <tr>
        <td width="80" align="center" valign="top"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"></font></td>
        <td valign="top" class="j"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><br>
            <div style="padding-top:0.8em;"><img alt="" height="1" width="1"></div>
            <div class="lh"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/JonathanRaveh/20150506/242840/Death_of_the_app_keyword__whats_next.php"><b>Death of the app <b>keyword</b> – what&#39;s next?</b></a><br>
                <font size="-1"><b><font color="#6f6f6f">Gamasutra (blog)</font></b></font><br>
                <font size="-1">Yes, app <b>keywords</b> are dying. If you search the web you may find insightful stories about apps that gained massive recognition due to the clever use of <b>keywords</b>. Many companies and services (such as Sensor Tower) offer developers tools to help them&nbsp;...</font><br>
                <font size="-1" class="p"></font><br>
                <font class="p" size="-1"><a class="p" href="http://news.google.com/news/more?ncl=d4b6j-gMxFN1VKM&amp;authuser=0&amp;ned=us"><nobr><b>and more&nbsp;&raquo;</b></nobr></a></font></div>
            </font></td>
    </tr>
</table>
1 pass
```

This regex, `".*?&amp;url=(.*?)"`, is looking between the first double quote and last of an href and capturing everything after `&amp;url=`. In the examples I've seen every instance has the URL as the last parameter. This regex will NOT work if the URL is the not the last parameter because it using a check that looks for the last double quote or an entitied ampersand; that'd be `("|&amp;)`. I could see that cutting off parameters from URLs though; if they had additional `GET` parameters. Another thing I never saw in these URLs was them using the `GET` parameters. Take out the `die('1 pass');` and give it a try or keep the `die` in if you want a small sample at first.

Comment: This was awesome thank you! Worked great. If it weren't for mhall's answer I would have accepted yours as the winning answer. But I'm using both of your codes now, for editing both $desc and $link. Thanks chris85, much <3